# 301 Redirect Adding Query to End of Target URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I can't seem to find a solution that works for my particular situation, despite many others having similar issues. When I try to create a 301 redirect for a URL that has already been rewritten, the redirect works, but appends a query string to the end of the target URL, which references the URL to be redirected. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /dir1/dir2/dir3/ http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir5/
```

results in

```
http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir5/?&a=/dir1/dir2/dir3/
```

Comment: Are there any other rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, there are many many other rules on my .htaccess and also in the httpd.conf file (large e-commerce site) The initial URL, has already been rewritten prior to implementing this redirect. Because the redirect works as intended, bar the query being appended, I am hopeful there may be some simple solution to strip the query from the target URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the  `Redirect` rule above is appending the QS params, so it is likely another rule in your .htaccess.

You also need to verify when the additional QS params are being added, before the first redirect or in a subsequent redirect.  You can to this using an HTTP debugging proxy e.g. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Alternatively, you can use the place the equivalent rule below at the top of your .htaccess, before any other rules and see if the extraneous QS params are still there.

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/dir3/$ http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir5/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

If they are still present, something else in your .htaccess is matching `http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir5/` and adding the QS value

Posting the relevant portions of your .htaccess, or the entire thing if you can would help

Comment: I'm going to try this rule in the httpd.conf file, before the main rewrite rule as it is not working even at the start of the .htaccess file. I'll post results. Thank you!

Comment: @KevinGleeson if you move to httpd.conf, you need to add a leading `/` to the pattern match ie `RewriteRule ^/dir1/dir2/dir3/$ http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir5/ [NC,R=301,L]`. Also, in the .htaccess file, it should be before any other rules, but after the `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /` directives

Comment: Thanks again Ulrich!! I added this to the httpd.conf file (with the leading /) and it seems to be working fine now. Do you know if it is a bad idea to have redirects exits in httpd.conf rather than the .htaccess?

Comment: @KevinGleeson .htaccess is slower than httpd.conf, so the latter is better. However, if you have more than one domain that could match, you may want to use a RewriteCond directive just before this rule e.g. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$` to limit the rule to just `www.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks again for all the VERY helpful info. One last question. The rule I applied above, will only affect that URL's with those specific directories, regardless of the domain name, correct?

Comment: @KevinGleeson express your gratitude by accepting this post as the answer, by clicking the check-mark on the left. And welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: @Gerben - Done, I didn't see that there, and thanks for the welcome...impressed so far :)